# jQuery dialog box shows only once

Tags: jquery, dialog

I have a table that holds dynamic messages from users and admin has ability to reply to these messages by clicking reply. Works perfectly. Problem is there are links to open the user message in a dialog, so they can see the full user message, same with their reply (if they have replied). They can see the dialog box only ONCE. When clicking on it again it doesn't show.

Any help would be appreciated

TABLE

```
foreach($content as $row)
{
    //print_r($row);
    echo '<tr data-id="'.$row['ConID'].'" input type="hidden" value="'.$row['ConID'].'">';
    echo '<td data-cn="'.$row['ConName'].'">'.$row['ConName'].'</td>';
    echo '<td data-em="'.$row['ConEmail'].'">'.$row['ConEmail'].'</td>';
    echo '<td data-cm="'.$row['ConMessage'].'" >'.substr($row['ConMessage'],0,30).'<a href="#" class = "open"> ...more</a><div class = "dialog"> <p>'.$row['ConMessage'].'</p></div></td>';
    echo '<td data-dt="'.$row['ConDate'].'">'.date('d/m/y', strtotime($row['ConDate'])).'</td>';
    if($row['Replied'] == 0){
        echo '<td data-rp="'.$row['Replied'].'">No</td>';
    }
    else{
        echo '<td><a href="#" class="openReply">See Reply</a><div class = "dialogReply"><p>'.$row['Reply'].'</p></div></td>';
    }
    if($row['Replied'] == 0){
        echo '<td><input type="button" class="replySender" id="replySender" value="Reply"/></td>';
    }
    else{
        echo'<td>Replied</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(".dialog").hide(); $(".open").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".dialog").dialog();  
});
$(".dialogReply").hide(); $(".openReply").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".dialogReply").dialog();  
});
```

Comment: Are the second dialogs created dynamically?

Comment: @VIDesignz, Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: @VIDesignz, when clicking on the anchor tag which holds the class ="openReply" and class="open" it opens the respective divs (div class="dialog" and div class="dialogReply" which holds the messages. Is that what you mean?

Comment: you should probably use an element ID rather than the class `.dialog`. Altho, knowing more about how your HTML is laid out would make a key difference. Could you make a [***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/) of the problem?

Comment: Its cool...I meant are the dialogs already existing or are they created on the fly, as the user clicks open or reply

Comment: @VIDesignz they are created on the fly

Comment: @SpYk3HH i used a class because it's in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

The reason of why the second time doesn't work, is because when you "run" it for first time $('#my_div').dialog(), this will move the element #my_div to the root of the body into to a wrapper(DIV), so $.next() will fail the second time because the element is not longer there!; my suggestion  will be set ID to the dialogs and save those ids on your anchors(). i.e.

```
<td>
    <a href="#" class="openReply" data-dlg-id="random-id-1">See Reply</a>
    <div class="dialogReply" id="random-id-1">
        <p>My Reply</p>
    </div>
</td>
<td>
    <a href="#" class="openReply" data-dlg-id="random-id-2">See Reply</a>
    <div class="dialogReply" id="random-id-2">
        <p>Other Reply</p>
    </div>
</td>
```

and you javascript may look like:

```
$(".dialogReply").hide();

$(".openReply").click(function(){
      var $dlg = $('#'+ $(this).attr('data-dlg-id'));
      if ($dlg.hasData('dialog'))
        $dlg.dialog('open');
      else
        $dlg.dialog();
});
```

I hope this helps. best!

Comment: On an alternate note, he could "pre-establish" the dialogs with `$(".selector").dialog({ autoOpen: false });` and then open them on command with `.click(function() { $(".selector").dialog("open");`

Comment: you are right on that, and also will be much faster. or also depending in how many "dialogs" you will need, you can init each dialog on the click, this will speed the initial load(again depending how many dialogs will be needed)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply everyone. I have it sorted.

So the div is removed once clicked on. Fixed it by using jquery clone():

> $(".dialog").hide();
>
> $(".open").click(function(){
>        $(this).next(".dialog").clone().dialog();  });
>            $(".dialogReply").hide();
>            $(".openReply").click(function(){
>         $(this).next(".dialogReply").clone().dialog();  });